# Import mustache Template using parameters Java Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, mustache

I need to make something like this using Mustache and Spring MVC:

```
{{> /WEB-INF/views/'{{content}}'.html}}
```

Where `{{content}}` is an object from Spring MVC:

```
model.addObject("content", "home");
```

Comment: This really isn't enough information to know what you are trying to do. Are you trying to use mustache as a templating engine for spring mvc?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding this character?

```
 {{#content}}
```

Here you have a very good example about how to integrate Spring MCV with mustache  http://java.dzone.com/articles/integration-spring-mvc-and-0

Answer (score 0):

Basically the expression which you're using "{{> *partial name*}}" is used to include a mustache partial within another mustache template.
Where, a partial is nothing but a Mustache template  that can be included/imported within another template.

So for instance, if you have 2 Mustache templates

1. main.mustache
2. home.mustache
   Then, your 'main.mustache' will have code like this:

   ```
   {{#content}}
          {{> /WEB-INF/views/home.html}} 
   {{/content}}
   ```

FYI, Mustache manual - https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html